# web page display on Windows 10 Edge Browser combination

Tags: layout, browser, rendering, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have new web pages that display properly when run through Browserstack for Windows 10/Edge browser combination.  However the owner is demonstrating that on her desktop monitor, the layout is not as per design with random element sizing issues.  She claims she's never adjusted any display size settings and has been using the out of the box settings since she purchased the monitor.

- Does anyone have any feedback as to running across the same issues with site pages rendering fine in Browserstack or Browserling, but not rendering accurate layout for desktop computers?
- Do MS browsers still have compatibility setting issues?

Comment: Has the user got a high DPI monitor? If so the Zoom setting might be applied in the browser. In some instances I suspect this could alter the way CSS sizing might work. Do you have an example page where the sizing issue is present?

Comment: As Martin stated, DPI is important. Have her press Ctrl + 0 to ensure the browser is zoomed to 100% as well. Also worth considering is feature support; she may be on a build of Edge that either has, or does not have, experimental flags enabled, or certain features. All of these could lead to layout issues. We would need specifics.

Comment: Thank you, both.  It turned out that the monitor was high DPI and the browser was configured at a much lower view percentage in order to offset.